# A calendar for select date for birthday

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to select previous days from today's date from a calendar (for birthdate). Is there any way to validate selected date (check if it is previous date or future date) or any function like MaxDate() for calendars?

Comment: we have to see the code,

Comment: You should add some code what you have tried before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I need to say you should tag your question JQuery also.
I think you want something like this. you can use `maxDate` attribute and set it to today [`new Date()`].
Then if a user want to bypass and put future date then you can validate it.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    maxDate:new Date(),
    changeYear:true,
    changeMonth:true,
    format:'dd/mm/yyyy'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
function validate(){
    if(new Date(document.getElementById('datepicker').value) > new Date()){
        alert("You entered future date, that is not valid");
        document.getElementById('datepicker').value='';
    }else{
        alert("Date is correct");
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
<input type="button" value="validate" onclick="validate()"/>
```